# How to copy something to Apache's www-directory using a GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, apache-http-server

i am using ubuntu 9.10 and when i copy a folder from the desktop to the www directory from lamp it says permission denied. im not doing it through terminal but how can i make myself root level to copy and edit/delete the files that i need to.

Comment: Please associate your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/users/210956?tab=accounts That will make you the owner of http://superuser.com/questions/70466/how-to-set-my-ubuntu-account-to-super-user-at-all-times again, and allow you to comment to answers at this question again. Please read the FAQs and understand this is not a forum. Please delete the answer at http://superuser.com/questions/70466/how-to-set-my-ubuntu-account-to-super-user-at-all-times/70469#70469 when done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of always having to run "gksudo nautilus", lets try something easier

My www folder is not owned by root but by me, I want to be admin of the www folder, and I suppose you want the same.

So we're going to make you owner

```
sudo chown <your_username> <path of your www folder> -R
```

In my case it was

```
sudo chown jeffrey /var/www/ -R
```

This will make you the owner of the folder, -R means recursive, thus it will make you owner of all subfolders as well.

To make sure you got enough read and write rights

```
sudo chmod 755 <path of your www folder> -R
```

This will grant you read, write and execute rights, and it will grant other users the right to read and execute it, 744 won't work, because you'll get a "permission denied" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can press F2 and enter **gksudo nautilus** if you are using the default file manager. This will run nautilus wit elevated privileges. I'd recommend against doing all operations like this though.